# Show html when called from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I know that similar questions can be found, but no answer worked for me. I want to show a html, for example `<h5>Your password is incorrect</h5>` when i encounter bad credentials at login. So this code should be "made alive" from inside the controller. Here's how mine looks like:

```
( function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app.home' )
        .controller( 'ploginController', ploginController );

    ploginController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$location', '$state', '$http' ];

    /* @ngInject */
    function ploginController( $scope, $location, $state, $http ) {

        $scope.submit = function () {
            $http.post( '/api/v1/person/login', $scope.add, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            } ).then( function ( respSucc ) {
                $state.go( 'layout.listcampaigns' );
                return respSucc;
            }, function ( respErr ) {
//i think code revealing method should be HERE, but how??
                return respErr;
            } );
        };
    }

} )();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` for that.

First, in your controller:

```
$scope.loginIncorrect = false;

...

$scope.submit = function () {
    $http.post( '/api/v1/person/login', $scope.add, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    } ).then( function ( respSucc ) {
        $scope.loginIncorrect = false;
        $state.go( 'layout.listcampaigns' );
        return respSucc;
    }, function ( respErr ) {
        $scope.loginIncorrect = true;
        return respErr;
    } );
};
```

then in your html:

```
<h5 ng-if="loginIncorrect">Your password is incorrect</h5>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this??

```
<h5 ng-show="showError">Your password is incorrect</h5>
```

And within your controller:

```
  function ploginController( $scope, $location, $state, $http ) {
        $scope.showError =false;
        $scope.submit = function () {
            $http.post( '/api/v1/person/login', $scope.add, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            } ).then( function ( respSucc ) {
                 $scope.showError =false;
                $state.go( 'layout.listcampaigns' );
                return respSucc;
            }, function ( respErr ) {
                  $scope.showError =true;
//i think code revealing method should be HERE, but how??

            } );
        };
    }
```